# In a .bat can text variable content be used in place of text file with WinMsg.exe?

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, messagebox, io-redirection

In the batch file I am writing which suffices for my need, I'm calling an app (WinMsg.exe) that creates a messagebox using text input.  It offers two input switches, -m for text quoted or in a named variable containing text, and -f to read input from a text file, which can be taken from a named variable.  The -m limit is 255 chrs while the -f limit is longer.  The text I want as input is >255 chrs and is stored in one or more variables.  I can use multiple variables with -m but it breaks when the total exceeds 255 chrs.  So it appears -f will have to be used.  My question is, if -f is expecting a filename, is there a way to "disguise" or somehow redirect my text string variables to be read as if they were actually contained in a file, and without first writing the variable content to a file?  I've not seen any questions with quite the same objective and I have doubts that it is even possible but I want to be sure.

Comment: If you've determined that you must use the `-f`ile, option, then you must by virtue of that provide a file as input. What's stopping you from writing to a temporary file reading it in as input and deleting it again? _the read/write option is unlikely to be noticeably less efficient_.

Comment: While is entirely possible to do that without adverse performance, I'm concerned that if there is a high frequency of writes and the disk is SSD then it would cause a reduction of the disk lifespan.  Maybe.  If it can be avoided I'd prefer to.

Comment: I agree with @Compo. Sounds like you are using [Bill Stewart's WinMsg](http://www.westmesatech.com/wast.html)

Comment: I am using that app.  The one thing I haven't tried is set "-f=-m" or would it be "-f=!-m!"?   (I'm joking.  I think!)

Comment: I doubt very much that you can avoid it if the utility has the limitations you've mentioned. You'll therefore need to use a file, find another utility/language or propagate the message area with less characters.

Comment: @iYAMGzORM, a ramdisk should do it for you. Still file write/read, but never hits your SSD or spinning disk: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=MSbKW-WMCIKZ0gLGtbbABg&q=ramdisk+windows+10&btnK=Google+Search&oq=ramdisk&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l10.1104.2606..5207...0.0..0.48.284.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0i10.9RsyUrMgTac

Comment: @jwdonahue, that is a good idea but does require a third party program.  The newer versions of Windows Server do allow you to create RAM DISKS with Powershell though.  I can't find any documentation on if it can be done on Windows 7 or Windows 10.  I think this is because a Server Role needs to be enabled which would not be part of Windows 7 or Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to think about your SSD. A high end SSD with plenty of free space in a home computer lasts centuries.

This reads from StdIn by line and displays in a Msgbox

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    MsgBox Inp.Readline
Loop
```

Or the whole file

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
MsgBox Inp.ReadAll
```

To use

```
Cscript //nologo "C:\folder\file.vbs" < "c:\windows\win.ini"
```

Comment: The MTBF is definitely higher than in the past, but don't they still slow down with increased use?

Comment: MTBF is a measure of reliability not lifetime. A 100,000 hour MTBF means that if you run 100,000 of them one will fail each hour.

Comment: I know what it means. The question still stands, don't they slow down with age? Has that curve changed substantially?

Comment: Under normal circumstances your drive will break with age before it reaches it operating life. Writing win.ini every second to a 1 terabyte drive will use up 1/3000th of your operating life in 34 years.